# Arch Linux: Webcam Virtual Background Setup

Tags: arch-linux, camera, skype, microsoft-teams

I have tried various tools like fakecam and blog posts like this (https://elder.dev/posts/open-source-virtual-background/),

however, I just can't get anything to run on my setup (Arch Linux).

Can someone help me out and write me a how-to for dummies on how to get a virtual background or blurred background for conferencing tools like Skype, Zoom, Teams on Arch Linux?

Comment: It would be nice if arch/manjaro instruction could be added to https://github.com/floe/backscrub

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work in my Manjaro (Arch-based) Linux with this (thanks to the hint [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ManjaroLinux/comments/kseuyq/comment/gifjt0o/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3))

1. Install the current Linux headers:

   ```
    sudo pacman -S "linux$(uname -r | awk -F. '{print $1$2}')-headers"
   ```
2. Install (and build) the `v4l2loopack-dkms`

   ```
    sudo pacman -S v4l2loopback-dkms
   ```
3. Load the module with the option for [fakecam](https://snapcraft.io/fakecam):

   ```
    sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 video_nr=20 card_label="fakecam" exclusive_caps=1
   ```

   (you may need to unload it if you have it already in, with `sudo modprobe -r v4l2loopback`)
4. Now `fakecam` (the snap installed with the package manager) works, after enabling it with `snap connect fakecam:camera`.

   [image: fakecam output]

**...for quite small values of "working":***

1. It's quite slow,
2. It fails to detect my body --- the floating head is a bit unnerving
3. Teams for Linux is unable to access the stream (black camera), so it's of little utility.

I will try later, or let this open to other people, to see if with https://github.com/floe/backscrub works better.

Comment: I have found if Teams shows a black camera (and `ffplay` is similarly corrupted) it's because the v4l2loopback device got confused about supported video formats.  Unloading and reloading the module (or presumably deleting and recreating the loopback devices) fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just documented a solution for this on the [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/V4l2loopback#Using_a_background_image_in_video_conferencing).

In short, I installed the `obs` program along with the `obs-backgroundremoval` plugin, and set up a "scene" with an image overlaid by the real webcam after the background was removed via that filter.

`obs` has native support for feeding the final combined image to a virtual webcam and this worked fine for me with Teams.

`obs` also supports multiple scenes, so you can easily transition between different background images and effects with a single button click, which is nice.

It also supports background videos, multiple webcams in the same feed, text overlays, etc. so it is a pretty versatile solution, if a little overkill for this type of use.